# Craigslist Notifications App that sends new postings to my email/sms/rss

Tags: php, mobile, craigslist

What are the best approaches to build a "Craigslist Notifications" software that shoots new postings directly to my email/sms/rss?

For example, I am constantly refreshing the "Free" category waiting for new postings.

Comment: If/when they start supporting http://code.google.com/apis/pubsubhubbub/ it'll be a lot easier.

Comment: This is especially important because, as of Feb 2013, Google has stopped indexing CraigsList posts. The old trick of using Google Alerts no longer works. Nor does search for "car site:craigslist.org".

Answer (score 1):

I can say anything for iPhone but on Android I would use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to to periodically check the resource (Craigslist in your case) for updates. Once update is detected process and post to RSS or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

There' s a "craigslist notifications" application for android where you can setup notifications every couple minutes for new postings based on the keywords and price parameters you set.  I would look at how that application is coded since it is written in open source. :)

Comment: we don't do keywords here. Use tags for that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of CraigsNotifica for android. The idea is to use AlarmManager like droidin.net said.